# How to use gatttool non-interactive mode

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I want to write `gatttool` in non-interactive mode.

```
$ sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b 78:A5:04:44:0A:57 -I
[78:A5:04:44:0A:57][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to 78:A5:04:44:0A:57
Connection successful
[78:A5:04:44:0A:57][LE]> char-write-cmd 0x0025 ff
```

I'm changing color of light that is using bluetooth.

What is the equivalent by using non-interactive mode?
I tried like this, but it doesn't change the color of light and to stop it I must use `ctrl+c`. There is no message at all.

```
sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b 78:A5:04:44:0A:57 --char-write -a 0x0025 -n ff
```

How can I write the command?

#### Environment:

I'm using `Raspberry Pi` and `Rasbian`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the option is not `--char-write` but a `--char-write-req`.

Total command must be:

```
sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b 78:A5:04:44:0A:57 --char-write-req -a 0x0025 -n ff
```