# Multiple BLE devic connection using gatttool

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

To monitor multiple BLE devices and record the incoming data.

In order to achieve this I should be able to connect to multiple ble devices. Right now I can open one interactive mode using gatttool and connect to the ble device (On raspberry pi). If I want to connect to one more ble device I have to open a new terminal window.

Can anyone help me on how to connect to multiple ble devices keeping the target in mind.

Comment: Write your own code using python, glib or qt dbus bindings.

Comment: Or you could not use the interactive mode instead?

Comment: @User404 How can I connect to multiple ble devices using interactive mode?  Any help would be useful.

Comment: You can't. At least not 1 command (which is logical). You should write a program or script which uses these non-interactive command. Ex; of non-interactive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326597/how-to-use-gatttool-non-interactive-mode