# Gatttool non-interactive mode --char-write

Tags: linux, shell, bluetooth-lowenergy, non-interactive

Still asking about BLE devices and `gatttool`.

I'm able to send a char-write-cmd in interactive mode, but I'm not able to do the same in non-interactive.

This is what I send in interactive mode :

```
gatttool -I

[]> connect BTADDR

[BTADDR]> char-write-cmd 0x0040 01

[BTADDR]> exit
```

In this way I start the Alert service, which in my case makes the buzzer sounds.

In theory, the non-interactive mode should be:

```
gatttool -b BTADDR --char-write -a 0x0040 -n 01
```

But this do not send the request command event to the board, I'm checking it using a dev board.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Interactive mode works, but non-interactive mode doesn't. I can send a write-request in non-interactive mode, but I can't send a write-command in non-interactive mode.  I've looked at the source code for gatttool and I can't see any obvious error. Were you able to get it working?

Answer (score 5):

The manual (non-interactive) way to read or write to your BLE peripheral:

To write and receive reply once: (depending on how you configure your BLE device)

```
sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx --char-write-req -a 0x0025 -n ff
```

To write and receive reply indefinitely: (Until you disconnect from BLE device or stop your Bluetooth client)

```
sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx --char-write-req -a 0x0025 -n ff --listen
```

Notice I only added the --listen option at the end. This mechanism only works if you configure your BLE node (sensor or actuator) to read and reply.
sources::
[How to use gatttool non-interactive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326597/how-to-use-gatttool-non-interactive-mode)
[Bluetooth Low Energy: listening for notifications/indications in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657007/bluetooth-low-energy-listening-for-notifications-indications-in-linux)

All that said, I still do not think it is best to control or get values from a BLE device. My direction is to move forward and use an API (maybe in python) to do the job for you.

https://github.com/peplin/pygatt
This API has been proven to work with Raspberry Pi Jessie destro.

Comment: I still do not think it is best to control or get values from a BLE device-- Why ?

pyGATT uses gatttool CLI approach in its internal implementation.If you don't like use CLI approach, What I recommend is to implement Native Library using BlueZ Libs.