# Gatttool in non interactive mode

Tags: linux, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatttool

im trying to use gatttool to connect and set value on a Bluetooth le device.
I need this on non-interactive mode, but can only get the interactive mode working:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/x$ sudo gatttool -I
[                 ][LE]> connect XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Attempting to connect to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
Connection successful
[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][LE]> char-write-req 0x0047 00000000
Characteristic value was written successfully
[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][LE]> char-write-req 0x003f 2424242a008080
Characteristic value was written successfully
[XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX][LE]> exit
```

But i need something like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/x$ sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --char-write-req --handle=0x0047 --value=00000000
Characteristic value was written successfully
pi@raspberrypi:~/x$ sudo gatttool -i hci0 -b XX:XX:XX:XX:XX --char-write-req --handle=0x003f --value=2424242a008080
Characteristic Write Request failed: Attribute can't be written
```

First command is an authentication with PIN 0000 0000 and this Looks like it is working..
The second command failed, but i dont know why.

Is this possible with gatttool on non-interactive mode?

Comment: The non-interactive one has a disconnect occurring between the two commands.  Is the authentication PIN required for the second write to be successful?  If so, that's likely the problem.  I don't think you can chain more than one read or write in a single command.

Comment: Please refer to my answer to a similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303153/gatttool-non-interactive-mode-char-write/42731796#42731796